# Apple Distribution Cert has expired

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, apple-developer

I am new to Apple app development.

I had a Distribution Certificate that just expired. As a result I cannot upload a new version of my app to the app store.

Looking in my Key Management I see the expired Apple Distribution Certificate.

I right click on the associated **private** key and select - "**Request a Certificate From a Certified Authority With "Apple Distribution ...**"

A **Certificate Assistant - Certificate Information** pop up occurs.

I enter for User Email Address the email address of the apple account I use.

I right click on the expired distribution certificate and select Get Info to obtain the Common Name and I put that in as the Common Name.

I leave CA Email Address empty and select Saved to disk.

When I select save it gives me an error - The specified item could not be found in the keychain.

As a result I cannot create a valid CSR file that I can use on the developer.apple.com to create a new distribution certificate.

Can anyone provide some insight as to what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use Xcode to renew your certificate? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate.html

Answer (score 2):

If your certificate has been expired you have to generate a new one.

In the Keychain Access app, make sure you don't have any item selected and go to:

```
Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority...
```

[image]

After uploading the `.certSigningRequest` file to your Apple developer account and downloading the new certificate, you have to generate a new Provisioning Profile for your App ID.

Comment: Thank you. My issue was that I had something selected.